# Multi-line match according to specific rules

Tags: regex

How do I match any line containing `#Test` and also all next lines from it as long they start with:

- any amount of space followed by a `;`

Example:

```
 1.        ; #Test
 2.        ; bbbb
 3.    
 4.        ; #Test
 5.
 6.        ; aaa
```

Line 1 and 2 are `one` match, line 4 another match

This is what i got atm:
`\s*(#Test).*(\s*;.*)*`

https://regex101.com/r/HvPAxt/1

My current doubt is how to stop matching when an empty line is found.

Example2:

```
 1.        ; #Test
 2.        ; bbbb
 3. 
 4. xxxx
 5. ; #Test
 6. yyyy
 7.
 8.    ; #Test
 9.
 10.   ; bbb
```

Line 1 and 2 are `one` match

Line 5 another match

Line 8 is another match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your RE is that `\s` also matches newlines.

You need to use a regular expression that is explicit about newlines, since you have specific requirements about them.

So I would use `[ \t]*` to match spaces and tabs, instead of `\s*`:

```
[ \t]*(#Test).*(\n[ \t]*;.*)*
```

PS: Make sure you don't use the `s` option (single line) because then `.` will start matching the newline character too.

Comment: Your regex is not matching when its just a single line, ex: `; #Test`

Comment: I thought the next line had to start with ;, if I misread your question let me revise.

Comment: OK, just reread your question more carefully, you want all subsequent lines that start with ; to be included. I'll figure it out and edit my answer.

Comment: Fixed. I was just missing a `*` after the last block, so accept any number of subsequent lines that start with ;